# Duplicate Rows From HQL Query When Returning Bag Property

Tags: nhibernate, hql

in my query I am using multiple tables, some of which cannot be set up as normal nhibernate relationships, so I am forced to return rows made up of individual columns rather than instances of entities. One of the properties I want to return is a bag/list and my query goes something like this:

`select p.ID, p.SomeOtherField, elements(p.MappedBagField), o.AnotherField ... from Parent p, OtherClass o, ...`

The query works but the problem I am having is that I am getting back multiple rows when the bag contains more than one linked record. Is there any easy way to stop this from happening? I tried ***distinct p.ID*** but it didn't make any difference

[Edit]Would the Criteria API be more suited to this?[/Edit]

Comment: What happens when you remove the `elements` function?

Comment: If I remove the elements part then I get an exception saying "illegal syntax near collection" followed by the query text.

Comment: what do you want the result to look like?

Comment: Hi, I would like one row for each Parent record including a list of associated child records (i.e. the MappedBagField property). At the moment I am getting the list in the results but I get duplicate rows if the list contains more than one record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're just trying to get a list of parents with a loaded collection, plus some data from other entity, is this correct?

In that case:

```
var parents = session.CreateQuery(@"
    select p, o
    from Parent p, OtherClass o
    join fetch p.MappedBagField
    ...")
    .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
    .List<object[]>();
```

Each item of the result has two elements, [0] is the Parent, [1] is the OtherClass.

Comment: Unfortunately as I said in my original question, I also need to retrieve columns from some other tables using a manual join.

Comment: @James: Edited to add OtherClass.

Answer (score 0):

That's the semantics of a Bag.  A Bag allows duplicate entities.
Instead of using a Bag (List), try to use a Set (`ISet`).  NHibernate should normally filter out the duplicates then.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of distinct p.ID use **DISTINCT p** (without the *.ID* field)

I had the same problem with duplicate result rows. This solved my problem:

```
session.CreateQuery(
  "SELECT DISTINCT p, o
   FROM ParentClass AS p,
        OtherClass AS o
   INNER JOIN p.mappedBagField as bagField
   WHERE ...
   AND bagField.id IN (:interestingIds)")
.setParameterList("interestingIds", {1,2,3,4});
.list();
```

**Explanation:**

*ParentClass* and *OtherClass* are two separate classes with **no** (hibernate mapped) relationship.

*ParentClass.mappedBagField* is a collection to a **third** hibernate mapped class.

In the example above I am looking for rows with the *interestingIds* 1, 2, 3 and 4.

If a *ParentClass* dataset has two *mappedBagField* entries with the ids 2 and 4, then the (original) SELECT will match the above *interrestingIds* twice!

This results in two rows.

Adding DISTINCT p to the SELECT omits duplicate results: every row will appear only **once** (even though there are multiple *interestingId* hits).